# How do I create a timer in Godot?

Tags: timer, godot, destroy, gdscript

How do I create a timer in Godot which destroys the script's object after a given amount of time? I am looking to remove bullets from a game after a while to reduce lag.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 11):

There is a `Timer` node that you can use. You can add it as a child, set the wait time (in seconds) - you could set it as one shot, and auto start - connect the `"timeout"` signal to your script, and on the method call `queue_free` to have the `Node` (and children, which includes the `Timer`) freed safely.

---

You can do that from code too, if that is what you prefer. So, let us go over what I just said, but instead of doing it from the editor, let us see the equivalent code:

Create a `Timer`, add it as a child:

```
var timer := Timer.new()
add_child(timer)
```

Set the wait time (in seconds):

```
timer.wait_time = 1.0
```

Set as oneshot:

```
timer.one_shot = true
```

Instead of setting it to auto start (which would be `timer.autostart = true`), let us start it:

```
timer.start()
```

Connect the `"timeout"` signal to a method. In this case, I'll call the method `"_on_timer_timeout"`:

```
timer.connect("timeout", self, "_on_timer_timeout")

func _on_timer_timeout() -> void:
    pass
```

Then in that method `_on_timer_timeout`, you can call `queue_free`:

```
timer.connect("timeout", self, "_on_timer_timeout")

func _on_timer_timeout() -> void:
    queue_free()
```

Answer (score 8):

Edit: I stand corrected, the best approach is to use a callback like Theraot's answer says:

```py
func _on_timer_timeout_funcname() -> void:
    # Do stuff here...
    queue_free() # removes this node from scene

var timer := Timer.new()
timer.wait_time = 1.0 # 1 second
timer.one_shot = true # don't loop, run once
timer.autostart = true # start timer when added to a scene
timer.connect("timeout", self, "_on_timer_timeout_funcname")
return add_child(timer)
```

I'm leaving my answer below here for people who are more comfortable with a sequential approach, but it can be a bit more tricky to deal with.

---

In **Godot 4**, there's an easy way to do this:

```py
# Do some action
await get_tree().create_timer(1.0).timeout # waits for 1 second
# Do something afterwards
queue_free() # Deletes this node (self) at the end of the frame
```

**Important: if you do this in the `_process()` or `_physics_process()` functions**, more **timers** get **created every frame**, which causes several runs to occur all at once before then running the following code. To handle this, simply track whether a timed event is happening.

Example in the `_process()` with simple attack logic:

```py
var attack_started = false;

func _process(delta):
    if attack_started:
        print("Not attacking, attack code running in background")
        return
    else:
        attack_started = true
        prepare_attack()
        await get_tree().create_timer(1.0).timeout # wait for 1 second
        begin_attack()
        attack_started = false
```

This `await` keyword **works with everything that emits signals**, including **collision events!**

FYI: `yield` was replaced with `await` in Godot 4, and `await` really just waits for a signal/callback to complete:

```py
await object.signal
```

`get_tree().create_timer(5.0)` will create a timer that runs for 5 seconds, and then has a `timeout` callback/signal you can tap into.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Was able to translate this to C# for my usecase.  Added another answer for the C# code too.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use the `SceneTreeTimer`, like in the following code:

```
func die(delay: float):
    yield(get_tree().create_timer(delay), "timeout")
    queue_free()
```

Please refer to Godot Engine's [documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_scenetreetimer.html?highlight=create_timer()).

Answer (score 0):

To build off of slay's answer...

In C# you can write

```
await ToSignal(GetTree().CreateTimer(1.5f), "timeout");`
QueueFree();
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase you don't want to instance a timer, You can also use `_process()` if you simply need a count down:

```bash
extends Node

signal timeout

var count_down=5

func _process(delta): # or you can use _physics_process()
    count_down-=delta
    
    if(count_down<=0):
        emit_signal("timeout")
        set_process(false)
```

Although this might have an error of ±`delta` time